# What is the lower bound on the dimension of the LOCAL imbedding of a General relativistic Lorentzian manifold in a pseudo-Euclidean spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, spacetime-dimensions

What is the lower bound on the dimension of the LOCAL imbedding of a General relativistic Lorentzian manifold in a pseudo-Euclidean spacetime?

Imbedding is Isometric embedding to me.

What about these particular cases: A wormhole (traversable) and a Schwarzschild black hole?
(I'd be grateful if the lower bound for a Global imbedding dimension for these two cases were also mentioned if there's any at all)

Penrose says that the local imbedding is usually at least of dimension 10 but I can't understand his reasoning:

[A Remarkable Property of Plane Waves in General Relativity
ROGER PENROSE](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.37.215)

Comment: Regarding the general version of the question, in the first sentence: you can try searching for Lorentzian generalizations of the **Nash embedding theorem**. Example: [On the $C^k$-embedding of Lorentzian manifolds in Ricci-flat spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.05911)